# How do I keep appending contents of a cell to a different sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have two columns of data. One is the a column named notes and the other is notes history. I update the notes section everyday, adding in today's note, a single or a double liner. My intention is to keep a record of everything I typed in this column which is similar to appending the notes to the history table

Comment: Welcome to SO. please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

You could try sheet events :

```
Option Explicit

Public Old_value As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    MsgBox "Old Value is: " & Old_value & vbNewLine & "New Value is: " & Target.Value

End Sub

Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Let us assume that Notes appear in column A
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        Old_value = Target.Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you error 1004, my intention is to fill in the column b, for example consider cells A1:A4 to have A, B, C, D today. Tomorrow I am going to enter E,F,G,H in A1:A4 (one alphabet in one cell). I want B1 to show A, E; B2 to show B, F; B3 to show C,G; B4 to show D,H. Basically append the values from A to it's corresponding cells in B, and this to happen only when the values change in A. So if I change A1,A2 only my B1 and B2 will be appending that data in a new line and B3 and B4 to stay the same. Please let me know if this is confusing.